# Ionic fill SVG dynamically according to selection

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, svg, ionic3, jquery-animate

I have a svg map in my ionic application, also there is a selection button to select districts. When i select one i need to fill relevant multiple svg parts.How can I achieve this?

[image: here]

Here is my code for svg map

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250.429 437.699">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1, .cls-2, .cls-3 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #2bd17b;
      }

      #Kandy{
        fill: #2bd17b;
      }


      #Matara{
        fill: #2bd17b;
      }

      .cls-1, .cls-3 {
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
      }

      .cls-1, .cls-2 {
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
<g id="Sri_Lanka" data-name="Sri Lanka" transform="translate(0.375 276.373)">
    <path id="Kandy"  class="cls-1" d="M115.848-109.977l.972,1"></path>
    <path id="Matara"  class="cls-1" d="M115.848-109.977l.972,1"></path>
    <path id="Galle"  class="cls-1" d="M115.848-109.977l.972,1"></path>
    <path id="Colombo"  class="cls-1" d="M115.848-109.977l.972,1"></path>
    ........
<g/
</svg>
```

Comment: just add the id conditional by your click state

Comment: @mr.void  how can i pass multiple ids to color?